# Scanning a single file using sonar runner

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

Is there any way to scan a single java file using sonar runner.

By default all the java files in the ***scr***. I do not want to exclude all the other files by writing a exclusion. Rather I would like to include only a single file for analysis.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "sonar.inclusions" property, like described [in the documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-ExcludingFiles).

For instance:

```
sonar-runner -Dsonar.inclusions=src/main/java/com/foo/MyClass.java
```